# Event handling in javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I've learned that you can declare event handlers within either the HTML or the Javascript. My question is, is it better to do so in the Javascript or the HTML? Does it make a difference? If so, why?

Comment: Almost always JavaScript. It's easier to keep track of and separates the HTML from the JavaScript.

Comment: How do I mark this question as 'answered'?

Comment: @user1157541 there are checkmarks under the voting arrows.

Comment: Also, [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Answer (score 1):

Almost always JavaScript. It's cleaner, easier to maintain and separates the HTML from the JavaScript.

For example, you could write this:

```
<button onclick="do_something(this)">Button 1</button>
<button onclick="do_something(this)">Button 2</button>
<button onclick="do_something(this)">Button 3</button>
<button onclick="do_something(this)">Button 4</button>
```

Or you could leave the HTML as just HTML and bind the event handler from within your script:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    // Do something
});
```

Comment: The same result can be achieved through event delegation, regardless of the attachment method used.

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends on your requirements. Adding an inline listener is no more difficult than adding a class or id, so whether you add them at the server (i.e. inline) or client (dynamically) depends on what suits a particular case.  Having them in–line makes it clear to anyone maintaining the code where the listeners are just by looking at the server code or generated HTMl. Otherwise, they must search through script files to find out where they are.

Just use whatever is mote efficient for you.